# Navegar entre diferentes pilhas em React Native com react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

> Objetivo: Navegar da screen **LoginScreen** para screen **MainScreen**

Codigo das rotas em **routes.js**:

```js
const AuthenticationNavigator  = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Login',
        headerShown: false, //desabilita a barra do topo
      },
    },
    Register: {
      screen: RegisterScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Cadastro',
      },
    },
  }, {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTintColor: '#FFF',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#121212',
      },
    }
})

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Main: {
    screen: MainScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: 'Main',
      headerShown: false,
    },
  },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Main',
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
    headerTintColor: '#FFF',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#121212',
    },
  }
})

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  /*
   * Rather than being rendered by a screen component, the
   * AuthenticationNavigator is a screen component
   */
  Auth: AuthenticationNavigator,
  Home: MainNavigator,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Auth'}
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer
```

Como estou tentando usar no arquivo **App.js**

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.isAuthenticationReady) {
      return (
        {}
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" backgroundColor="#121212" />
          {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <AppContainer /> : <AppContainer />}
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

Como eu uso o AppContainer no meu arquivo principal **App.js**? E como faço para navegar entre as Screens das diferentes stacks?

Answer (score 0):

O createAppContainer você vai utilizar apenas uma vez. Dentro do seu AppContainer, você pode ter dentro um StackNavigator, e dentro dele, cada elemento pode ser um componente (como no seu exemplo), ou um outro Stack.

Um outro exemplo seria você ter dentro do seu AppContainer um TabNavigator, e cada item ser um Stack.

Sendo assim, para funcionar a navegação entre telas, o seu AppContainer deve ter um Stack com os componentes Login, Register e Main. Ele ficaria da seguinte forma.

```
export const Intro = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Login',
        headerShown: false, //desabilita a barra do topo
      },
    },
    Register: {
      screen: Register,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Cadastro',
      },
    },
    Main: {
      screen: Main,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Main',
        headerShown: false,
      },
    },
  },{
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerTintColor: '#FFF',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#121212',
      },
    }
  })
);
```

Dentro de Login, para navegar para Main, você pode fazer o seguinte

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Main");
```

Cada componente de sua rota recebe uma props chamada "navigation", que vai permitir a navegação entre telas.  Se você criar um botão em sua página login e adicionar este código, deve funcionar.  Essa props apenas se aplica aos componentes da rota, os componentes abaixo por padrão não recebem esta props.

Aqui tem mais informações:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/connecting-navigation-prop.html

Comment: Mas eu queria separar em duas Stacks, uma de autenticação e outra da Main, onde vou adicionar mais funcionalidades, tentei fazendo o createSwitchNavigator, mas estou tento problemas, vou atualizar o codigo como esta atualmente